# What are the benefits of using FBJS vs. an iFrame with jQuery

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I am looking into turning a JavaScript app (using jQuery) into a facebook widget, and am wondering what the benefit of using FBJS is over an iFrame with the app's current JavaScript code & libraries...  Can any facebook app developers out there comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is actually moving away from FBML/FBJS and encouraging developers to use iframes for their pages and applications:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/402/

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/